# chrome.tabs.query not returning current tab URL as a match?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension where i need to check if the user has logged into a page or not.  When the icon is clicked the extension will open a new tab to a specified url.  If the user is not logged in the site will redirect them to the /login/ page instead.  After the page loads I am trying to read if the currentURL matches that of the login page.  If it does that I know they need to log in, and I inform them.  My problem is that using the query the extension retrieves not the url of the active tab, but the url that the tab was originally sent to.

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
    // Attempt to open Karmalicity get points page
    var getPoints = "http://www.karmalicity.com/get-points/";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: getPoints });

    // Check if the user is logged in
    var checkLog = "https://www.karmalicity.com/login/";
    var currentURL;

    setTimeout(function(){

        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            currentURL = tabs[0].url;
        });

        var check = checkLog.localeCompare(currentURL)

        if (check == 0){
            // If returns 0, user is not logged in
            alert("You need to be logged in to utilize this application!");
        }else { 
            // User is logged in
            alert("Returned with " + check + ". Should be zero for testing.");
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

The extension will return /get-points/ even though the actual tab is on /login/.
My permissions include both tab and activeTab.  What is the correct way to obtain the url?

**EDIT**
I have put the url check into the timeout, so that issue is now solved. However it still does not seem to check correctly.  When comparing the strings I am returning with -1.

Comment: You need to wait for that tab to load using chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener inside the callback for chrome.tabs.create. There are at least several examples of doing that on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.  Instead of checking two variables by comparing the strings, I ended up testing if the url includes the keyword "login".  By doing this I was also able to slim down the code.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
    // Attempt to open Karmalicity get points page
    var getPoints = "http://www.karmalicity.com/get-points/";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: getPoints });

    // Check if the user is logged in
    var check;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        check = (tabs[0].url).includes('login');

        if (check == true){
            // If returns true, user is not logged in
            alert("You need to be logged in to utilize this application!");
        }else { 
            // User is logged in
            alert("Logged in.");
        }
    });
});
```

Also by removing the timeout I can prevent any potential errors with functions running out of order.